# Notepad++ regex - how to remove the proxies from this list?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this list of user:pass:proxy

```
username1:password:124.144.86.130:3128
username2:password:124.144.86.238:3128
username3:password:124.144.86.180:3128
username4:password:128.20.185.250:3128
username5:password:124.144.164.40:3128
```

how to get rid of proxy and keep Username:password using regex?

I want only

```
username1:password
username2:password
username3:password
username4:password
username5:password
```

I've tried for `^[^:\r\n]*:[^:\r\n]*:` but it remove user:pass and keep the proxy..

Comment: Will this help you?  Find: `:\d.*`    replace with:  `nothing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\w.*?\:\w+
```

Here is an example match: https://regex101.com/r/SzcwGa/1

or, you can use Substitution to remove what you do not need: https://regex101.com/r/SzcwGa/2

Find: `(^\w.*?\:\w+)(.*)`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: I dont want to remove user:pass, I just want to remove "Proxy" your regex is removeing user:pass.

Comment: it is not removing it, it is matching it :) you can use Substitution to remove what you do not need: https://regex101.com/r/SzcwGa/2

Comment: I've tried `(^\w.*?\:\w+)(.*)` with replace `$1` it remove all lines and keep first line.

Comment: It removes all lines and keep the first line in notepad++ somehow!

Comment: Never mind its the 64-bit version of notepad++, it works with 32-bit notepad++ version.